# How to extract the URL of links on a web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download all the PDF files in the link below.

[Link](https://www.osapublishing.org/search.cfm?q=comsol&meta=1&cj=1&cc=1)

First, I tried to extract the URL of all the PDF links (links enclosed in red in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNCwf.jpg))

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 as ul

resp = ul.urlopen("https://www.osapublishing.org/search.cfm?q=comsol&meta=1&cj=1&cc=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'lxml')

f = open('url.txt', 'w')

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):

    f.write(str(link['href']) + '\n')

f.close()

----------------------------------------------------------------

<url.txt>
http://www.osa.org
#
https://www.osapublishing.org
#
#
#
#
/about.cfm

/aop
/ao
/as
/boe
/col
/jdt
/jlt
/jot
/jocn
/josaa
/josab
/josk
/optica
/ome
/oe
/ol
/prj
/jon
/josa
/on
/aop
/ao
/as
/boe
/col
/jdt
/jlt
/jot
/jocn
/josaa
/josab
/josk
/optica
/ome
/oe
/ol
/prj
/jon
/josa
/on
/conferences.cfm
/conferences.cfm
/conferences.cfm?findby=conference
/conference.cfm?meetingid=5
/conference.cfm?meetingid=124
/conference.cfm?meetingid=56
/conference.cfm?meetingid=144&yr=2015
/conference.cfm?meetingid=153&yr=2015
/conference.cfm?meetingid=131&yr=2015
/conference.cfm?meetingid=174&yr=2015
/conference.cfm?meetingid=109&yr=2015
#global-nav
/books/lasers/lasers.cfm
/oida/reports.cfm
http://www.osa-opn.org
/author/author.cfm
/submit/review/peer_review.cfm
/library/
/osadigitalarchive.cfm
/isp.cfm
http://imagebank.osa.org
/spotlight
/china/
#
/user
#
#
#
https://www.osapublishing.org
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
/
#
#
/user
#
#
/about.cfm
/conferences.cfm
/conferences.cfm
/conferences.cfm?findby=conference
/china/
/author/author.cfm
/submit/review/peer_review.cfm
/library/
/books/lasers/lasers.cfm
/oida/reports.cfm
http://www.osa-opn.org
http://imagebank.osa.org
/spotlight/
/china/
/about.cfm
/benefitslog.cfm
/contactus.cfm
#
/privacy.cfm
/termsofuse.cfm
https://account.osa.org/eweb/dynamicpage.aspx?sso=1&site=osac&webcode=loginrequired&url_success=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eosapublishing%2Eorg%2Fsearch%2Ecfm%3Fq%3Dcomsol%26meta%3D1%26cj%3D1%26cc%3D1%26usertoken%3D%7Btoken%7D
https://account.osa.org/eweb/Dynamicpage.aspx?webcode=forgotpassword*Site=osac
/privacy.cfm
http://www.osa.org/en-us/help/
```

But, it looks like the links I wanted to extract wasn't extracted.
How can I do that?

Comment: So you're targeting the View: PDF links right? The first one I see is: `<a target="_blank" href="viewmedia.cfm?URI=biomed-2014-BS3A.55&amp;seq=0&amp;origin=search">PDF</a>` Which could mean a few things, they are generated dynamically or called via AJAX. When I follow the link, I am taken to a page where I login or purchase. So it's not taking you directly to the PDF. How are you getting to the PDFs manually?

Comment: The second one loads a full pdf in the browser and it looks like is generated dynamically: https://www.osapublishing.org/view_article.cfm?gotourl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.osapublishing.org%2FDirectPDFAccess%2F6FA37648-E3C1-262B-6AF76128B6A12104_274099%2Foe-21-22-27371.pdf%3Fda%3D1%26id%3D274099%26seq%3D0%26mobile%3Dno&org= I would add a condition to look for 'pdf' in your script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some of them can be downloaded without login. I understand that the URLs of these links are not in the HTML source. Is there any way to open these links without their URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that PDF links you want to address are not inside the HTML-Source via 'https://www.osapublishing.org/search.cfm?q=comsol&meta=1&cj=1&cc=1'.

The PDF links are getting loaded by AJAX.

I guess you need to open the URL with POST and 'the' correct parameters/cookies set. Eg: "CFID=xxxxxxxx; CFTOKEN=xxxxxxxx; BIGipServerPubsWeb_HTTP=xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx; _ga=GAx.x.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx; _gat=1"

Your response will be JSON formatted. Objects will include 'result[0].data.has-pdf = true' to test for existing PDF. Links look like: 'fn:doc("/oe/21/22/27371/oe-21-22-27371.xml")/article/front/article-meta/abstract/p', so you need to match them to the PDF files.

BUT i guess they might have some IP checks or other security stuff, so maybe you are not able to get some data via POST from any domain other then the origin. Just a guess ;)

Comment: Some of the links do not require login, for example: `https://www.osapublishing.org/view_article.cfm?gotourl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.osapublishing.org%2FDirectPDFAccess%2F6FA37648-E3C1-262B-6AF76128B6A12104_274099%2Foe-21-22-27371.pdf%3Fda%3D1%26id%3D274099%26seq%3D0%26mobile%3Dno&org=` Here you can see the direct URL is passed to the CF Script